# Haskell conduit: How to send data downstream while producing a monadic value

Tags: haskell, conduit

I want to write a proxy, which would receive a header that indicates the destination IP, port, etc.

So I have something like this:

```
getHeader = do
    Just x <- await
    let (a, rest) = splitAt headerLen x
    return $ parseHeader a
    -- how to send the rest data downstream ??

(resume, header) <- clientSource $$+ getHeader
-- do something according to the header
```

The problem is that, sometimes the header and the subsequent data are sent together, and therefore `getHeader` consumes the subsequent data, which is supposed to be consumed by later conduits. So how can I send `rest` downstream?

Comment: Notice that you are assuming that the first chunk you get from `await` will contain the whole header. I think this is not guaranteed by most bytestring sources.

Comment: Can't you just use `clientSource $$+ Data.Conduit.Binary.take headerLen`? Then what you do with the 'resumable conduit' can depend on what you learn from `parseHeader` and any bytes beyond the header will be contained in the resumable conduit.

Comment: @Michael I didn't know there was such a function in conduit! thanks a lot.

Comment: +Michael's answer is probably the best one for this case, but in general: I think you're looking for the [`leftover`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-6.7/conduit-1.2.6.6/Data-Conduit.html#v:leftover) function.

Comment: I was going to mention `leftover`, since at first sight that's what's being asked for, but the other problem, about `await`, meant that the program would need a loop to replicate what must be going on in `Data.Conduit.Binary.take` anyway to make sure it got `headerLen` many bytes. (`take` of course uses `leftover`)

Answer (score 1):

You could also consider to use a parser wrapped into a conduit, for example [`Data.Conduit.Attoparsec`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-extra-1.1.13.2/docs/Data-Conduit-Attoparsec.html) in *conduit-extra*. The wrapper takes care of requesting as many input pieces as needed (in your case it can happen that the first piece is shorter than `headerLen`), and also of taking care of leftovers:

```
import Control.Monad.Catch
import qualified Data.Attoparsec.ByteString as P
import Data.Attoparsec.Types
import qualified Data.ByteString as BS
import Data.Conduit
import Data.Conduit.Attoparsec


parseHeader :: Parser BS.ByteString BS.ByteString
parseHeader = P.take headerLen -- do whatever parsing you need to get the header
  where 
    headerLen = 42

consumerHeader :: (MonadThrow m) => Consumer BS.ByteString m BS.ByteString
consumerHeader = sinkParser parseHeader
```

`Consumer` is defined as

```
type Consumer i m r = forall o. ConduitM i o m r
```

so `consumerHeader` takes `ByteString` as input, is polymorphic in the output as well as the monad, and returns the parsed `ByteString`.